# How to overwrite or alter data in child ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I have two simple ember components; a list component and a list-item component. Data gets passed as an array to the list where it runs an each loop and makes a list-item component for each item in the array.

I'd like to, within the list-item component, take the data being passed to it from its parent list component and overwrite it. Eventually I would like to do more than just overwrite it and use it as a parameter in a function to return a new, parsed, value.

For the sake of example, lets say that this is a list of tweets.

Here is my code.

ROUTER.JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('tweets');
});

export default Router;
```

TEMPLATES/TWEETS.HBS

```
{{tweet-list tweets=model}}
```

ROUTES/TWEETS.JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return[{
      tweetText: "this is an example  #request tweet text1 @user"
      },{
      tweetText: "tweet of the @text2 how #cool"
      }, {
      tweetText: "tweet toot took text3"
    }];
  }
});
```

COMPONENTS/TWEET-LIST/COMPONENT.JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
});
```

COMPONENTS/TWEET-LIST/TEMPLATE.HBS

```
<ul>
  {{#each tweets as |tweet|}}
    <li>{{tweet-item tweet=tweet}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

COMPONENTS/TWEET-ITEM/COMPONENT.JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
// model(){
// return "over written value here"
// }
});
```

COMPONENTS/TWEET-ITEM/TEMPLATE.HBS

```
{{tweet.tweetText}} - <!-- {{overwritten value here}} -->
```

I believe I have to do the overwriting in the COMPONENTS/TWEET-ITEM/COMPONENT.JS file ? How do I go about overwriting or, even better, returning a new value based off of the data passed down from the parent component?

Comment: Do you need the item to be overwritten in the parent array or just display overwritten value inside item component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different component properties for given and overwritten tweets. For example:

```
// components/tweet-item/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   // given tweet
   tweet: null,

   // overwritten tweet
   parsedTweet: Ember.computed('tweet', function() {
     return {
         tweetText: this.get('tweet').tweetText + ' #overwritten'
     };
   }),

   // you may also modify given tweet here
   // but the better approach to send action up
   // in favor of data-down-action-up principe

   actions: {
     publish: function(tweet) {
       this.sendAction('publish', tweet);
     }
   }
});

// components/tweet-item/template.hbs
tweetText: {{parsedTweet.tweetText}}
<button {{action 'publish' tweet}}> Publish </button>

// components/tweet-list/component.js
actions: {
  publish: function(tweet) {
    // your logic
  }
}

// components/tweet-list/template.hbs
<ul>
  {{#each tweets as |tweet|}}
    <li>{{tweet-item tweet=tweet publish='publish'}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```